# What is the difference between temporal "en" and "dum"?

Tags: prepositions

It seems that *I slept during the holiday* can be translated into two ways:

> Mi dormis *en* la festotago.
>
> Mi dormis *dum* la festotago.

Do they both mean the same?

Answer (score 8):

Your two sentences mean different things.

*Dum* implies duration. *En* suggests that something happened within the period.

- Mi dormis en la festotago.

At some point you slept.

- Mi dormis dum la festotago.

You spent your festival day sleeping.

Answer (score 2):

PMEG has a paragraph about this. http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/rolmontriloj/rolvortetoj/lokaj_rolvortetoj/en.html#i-sb8

*Dum* shows a duration (over which the action took place).
*En* can show one of two things

- a **point** in time
- the time needed to complete an action, basically the **point** in time when the action will be finished.

You can also have temporal *tra* and *por*.

*Mi dormis tra la festotago* - almost the same as with *dum*, but with emphasis on sleeping *through* the whole period.

*Mi ripozis por unu tago* - I took a break which lasted one day.